# Laravel 5 - Rest

Tags: rest, laravel, social-networking

Good morning,
I'm working on a laravel 5 social-network-like app and I'm trying to use Restfull controllers but I've found a problem

How can I avoid the resource for the user?

I mean, how can I do this:

```
Route::resource('{username}', 'UserController');
```

instead of this:

```
Route::resource('user/{username}´, 'UserController');
```

The first one takes me to index method inside UserController, but it must take me to show method, taking {username} as the id parameter.

Therefore I would make nested resources like
// user's photos index

```
Route::resource('{username}/photos´, 'UserPhotosController');
```

// show one photo (photo_id)

```
Route::resource('{username}/photos/photo_id´, 'UserPhotosController');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you are mixing up two different resources. `user` and `photos`.

Comment: itachi, that is a mention for a nested resource (UserPhotosController) which is used to manage the photos owned by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining this: `Route::resource('{username}', 'UserController');`

These are the routes that get generated by Laravel:

```
| GET|HEAD | {username}                     | {username}.index     | UserController@index   |
| GET|HEAD | {username}/create              | {username}.create    | UserController@create  |
| POST     | {username}                     | {username}.store     | UserController@store   |
| GET|HEAD | {username}/{{username}}        | {username}.show      | UserController@show    |
| GET|HEAD | {username}/{{username}}/edit   | {username}.edit      | UserController@edit    |
| PUT      | {username}/{{username}}        | {username}.update    | UserController@update  |
| PATCH    | {username}/{{username}}        |                      | UserController@update  |
| DELETE   | {username}/{{username}}        | {username}.destroy   | UserController@destroy |
```

This table shows that the `/{username}` route will go to the `UserController@index` method. Also, If you notice, the `show` route that gets generated is actually:

`{username}/{{username}}`

Therefore I wouldn't suggest to use the Resource route generator, instead is best if you defined the routes in an explicit manner. For example:

`Route::get('{username}', ['as' => 'username.show', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);`

Also, Laravel reads the routes in the order that they appear. When you define such dynamics routes, make sure that this routes are the last one in your route.php file. Example:

```
Route::get('about', 'StaticPagesController@about');
Route::get('blog', 'StaticPagesController@blog');
Route::get('contact', 'StaticPagesController@contact');
Route::get('{username}', ['as' => 'username.show', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);
```

Comment: I've found the same answer a couple other times, but not so well explained.

Thank you, I'll make it that way.